# Как построить эффективное кэширование

Tags: кэширование, memcached, php

У меня VPS сервер. Кожу на php, в качестве базы использую MySQL. В последнее время очень нужно повысить пропускную способность сервака.

Уже и так все кэшируется по файлам на жестком диске - это конечно повышает производительность в разы, но меня и этого теперь мало.

Расскажите что эффективней использовать для этих целей? Именно для кэширования. Из соседнего поста я узнал, что есть:

> memcache для кэширования данных
>
> apc - для кэширования пхпшечки

Но на сколько это эффективно, какие есть аналоги и что работает быстрее и надежней? Так же интересует установка, чтоб не запариваться и работало на всех серваках, хостингах.

Comment: так какие данные надо кешировать? :) от этого надо отттакиваться. в любом случае это будет нагрузка на проц.

Comment: на vps вы быстро упретесь в память, старайтесь кэшировать на клиенте. поменьше траффик попрямее логика и все получится.

Comment: LocalStorage, на мой взгляд, хорошее решение.

Comment: во первых настройки сайта должны быть в оперативке

во вторых наиболее часто используемые конструкции php должны быть тоже в оперативке

и самое главное в моем приложении будет инсталятор php (как в юми смс)

так вот нужно чтобы в большинстве случаев все работало и устанавливалось и не парило мозги пользователю

короче допустим смарти я пихнул в свой двиг и он установится не паря мозги, тоже самое должно быть и тут

Answer (score 8):

> > это конечно повышает производительность в разы, но меня и этого теперь мало

Для начала давайте определимся - чего вам мало?

Вы проводили тесты, измерения и вам выдало - php код выполняется слишком долго, в результате чего вместо 1000 человек можно обслужить только 100?

Надо ускорять там, где действительно это надо, а то получится - экономили, экономили, а оказалось на спичках экономим, хотя в кармане куча зажигалок.

Memcache и APC предназначены для разных целей (данные и код, как вы уже заметили).

Надо понимать, что обращение к PHP, если грубо, состоит из следующего:

1. открыли соединение к серверу на определенном порту, определили какой файл должен исполняться
2. интерпретатор прошелся по этому файлу (типа скомпилировал), отправил на выполнение
3. php-скрипт начал свое выполнение, выполнил нужные действия, получил определенные данные, вернул данные клиенту

Это если грубо, но смысл думаю ясен.

Если больше всего тормозит п.3 - значит в первую очередь необходимо кэширование данных,

Если п.2 - кэширование кода (дабы не интерпретировать каждый раз одно и тоже), либо перенос части функционала, например, на С/С++

Хотя может быть просто используется неоптимальный алгоритм?

Или может оказаться, что PHP-код отрабатывает быстро, даже очень быстро, но все равно тормоза есть.

> > повысить пропускную способность сервака

Может вы все-таки упираетесь в сеть? Пропускная способность сети может слишком маленькая, или настройки сервера не оптимальны (например, выставлено небольшое количество возможных подключений?)

В общем без конкретных тестов на узкие места трудно сказать что и как необходимо.

Но ведь вопрос не в этом? Вопрос - что лучше?

Ответ: memcache - кэширование данных, APC - кэширование кода. Что использовать? См. выше.

Comment: Однако в отпуск пора...

Вопрос был что лучше для кэширования кода и данных, а я как-то понял "что лучше для кэширования - memcache или APC"...

Что лучше для каждого - как-то не знаю) Поэтому мой ответ не стоит рассматривать как призыв использовать именно эти средства, возможно что они не самые эффективные, но мы пока используем именно их (т.е. и memcache, и APC).

Answer (score 3):

1. Используйте `javascript-MVC` фреймворки. Там можно закешировать все шаблоны, а данные будут приходить от `RESTfull`-сервера как JSON. В этом случае вы не будете париться о рендеринге шаблонов на стороне сервера. Это уменьшит нагрузку на файловую систему.
2. Как сказали выше - `Local Storage`, кешируйте сами данные на стороне клиента.
3. `Memcache` (хотя по мне лучше - `Redis`). Для кеширования результатов запросов и для хранения сессий. Меньше запросов к медленному MySQL и к файловой системе.
4. `APC` для ускорения php-сервера.
5. `nginx` вместо медленного `Apache`.

Примерно так выглядело мое последнее нагруженное приложение

Comment: Какие js-mvc фреймворки порекомендуете? И что за приложение, если не секрет, какая нагрузка, сколько серверов?

Comment: У нас все, что нужно подгружается вроде сразу, затем в зависимости от действий пользователя, ответа сервера и еще чего-нибудь (сам клиентами уже не занимаюсь) отображаем нужную страницу. Используем jQuery Mobile + Knockout. Первое - для шаблонов, второе - для автоматического обновления данных на клиенте.

Серверов пока около 10 (плюс-минус) - почти каждый выполняет свою функцию. Правда нагрузки пока нет - только готовимся в запуску)

Надеемся все пройдет хорошо